# date is not submiting in datatable

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to submit data in the data table. I have created one form for the date but it can't submit data into the data table.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="date" name="e_date">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    global $wpdb;

    $e_date=$_POST['e_date'];
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix .'pte_exam'; 
    $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name2,
            array('date' => $e_date)
         ); 
    echo '<script>alert("Question added");</script>';
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    exit;
 }
```

Comment: Your codesample needs some improvements for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $wpdb->show_errors(); try:

$wpdb->last_error();
or
$wpdb->last_query();

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors for more information.